# Mongoose Model не сохраняет поле типа `Object`

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Хочу сохранить модель после изминений:

```
Statistic.findOne({ 'user': user, 'type': type })
    .then(function(commonStatistic) {
    commonStatistic.data.words += words.length;
    commonStatistic.data.comments += comments.length;
    commonStatistic.data.visits++;
    commonStatistic.updated = Date.now();
    commonStatistic.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            // TODO: Add handler
        }
    });
});
```

Все поля, кроме поля (объекта) `data` сохраняются нормально, а дата не хочет ни в какую, что это за бред такой, все поля сохраняет а это нет, это баг или я не правильно что-то делаю?

**UPD:** Короче как оказалось просто так вложенные объекты не сохраняются, для того что бы они сохранялись при `save()` нужно, перед сохранением модели, их пометить: `commonStatistic.markModified('data');`. Мне данное решение помогло, но возможно есть решения лучше?

Comment: я при таких случаях в схеме модели указываю вложенную схему где указываю какие поля там будут

Comment: Да, но у меня так не получится, потому что объект `data` у меня может быть рандомной структуры, так было изначально задумано. Но за ответ спасибо, то есть получается он не сохраняет наверно именно из-за того, что у меня объект `data` простой объект и монгус просто не знает его схему, скорей всего из-за этого он и не сохранял.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я бы коротко сделал бы так:

```
const 
  query = {user, type},
  update = {
    '$inc': {
      'data.words': words.length, 
      'data.comments': comments.length, 
      'data.visits': 1
    },
    '$set': {
       updated: Date.now()
    }
  };
Statistic.update(query, update, callback);
```

данный пример не создаст инстанс модели в памяти (экономия))) и изменит 1 документ

если важно иметь под рукой результирующий документ то:

```
Statistic.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, callback);
```

Comment: Ну на самом деле вариант `commonStatistic.markModified('data');` Как то покороче выглядит... Но на счет того что при `save()` создается копия в памяти я и не знал, если это действительно так и это сильно влияет на производительность тогда да, лучше написать на пару строчек кода больше. Спасибо за пример.

Comment: марк модифаед и всякие доп заморочки вызывают доп поведения в монгузе что опять таки лишние телодвижения. а то что в примере оно тупо на низком уровне минуя монгуз вызывает монго-дб запрос. как бы монгуз берет имя коллекции с модели и тупо проксирует поля вызывая `updateOne` по протоколу mongodb

Comment: p.s. `save` не создает инстанс (: инстанс модели уже создан при вызове `findOne`. еще один p.s. если не нужен функционал монгуза при изьятии данных то можно экономить так: `Statistics.findOne(query).lean().then()` но учтите что `lean` не дополняет результирующий обьект мусором ODM-ки, так что `.save` не заработает. итог: пользуемся нужными фичами там где надо

Comment: да и еще при большой конкуренции запросов лучше всетаки делать операции инк/декремента на стороне базы, иначе 2 паралельных изменений на уровне ODM-ки могут друг-друга затирать, а в моем примере об этом заботится база данных и Вы не потеряете запрос.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за развернутый ответ!